# Bash script check if tilde '~' is an argument

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line-arguments, tilde

I have a simple bash script that can accept arguments that it will be treating as text strings, nothing more.

If I give it `~`, without quotes, then the home directory `/home/users/me` is what's parsed.  Quote it, `"~"`, it's fine.  The character "~" is what I want, not the home path.

Is there any way I can ensure an un-quoted `~` is treated exactly as the character "~", not the home directory alias?

Comment: No, it's interpretted by the shell before your script sees it.

Comment: The tilde expansion is being performed by your shell, not by the script. You can also disable tilde expansion by preceding the tilde with a backslash.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to do this? Can you not quote or escape your command line arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash shell is expanding the `~` on the command line before the argument is passed to your script.

There *might* be a bash option that you can change in your shell, but that would affect everything in your shell, which doesn't sound like what you want.

The short answer I think is no. There's nothing you can do in your script to change how the parent shell expanded any arguments before passing them to your script.

Comment: I don't see any shopt to disable `~` expansion. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: Thanks. Thought as much.